# Ruby HTTPNotFound Error with Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I have a ruby on rails application that is trying to access various links on Yahoo Sports and sometimes when it tries to reach a page, it gives me this error below. The error is consistent and any of the links it fails on, it always fails on. It is not a case of sometimes they work and sometimes they don't. You will find though that the page does exist and loads fine, so I'm not sure why it is giving me an error. Has anyone experienced this type of behavior before and if so, do you have any suggestions on how to get this to work?

> 404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for http://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/9893/
>   -- unhandled response

```
@client = Mechanize.new()
@client.request_headers = { "Accept-Encoding" => "" }
@client.ignore_bad_chunking = true

#works
#url = 'http://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/7307'

#doesn't work
url = 'http://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/9893'

result = @client.get(url)
```

Comment: Did you try accessing  the same url in browser from your machine? Are you sure there is no firewall (Access denied) thats blocking this url?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access it from my browser and it loads fine.  There are no firewalls.

Comment: single quotes for working url as well right...;)

Comment: Yep, just updated the post with that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure this out with mechanize, but I was able to get the URL from HTTParty.  If you do a rescue from a mechanize failure and retry by looking for a redirect URI you should be set:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'httparty'

@client = Mechanize.new()

url = 'http://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/9893'

begin
  result = @client.get(url)
rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError => e
  redirect_url = HTTParty.get(url).request.last_uri.to_s
  result = @client.get(redirect_url)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the redirect. Mechanize offers a method for that- follow_meta_refresh. Try adding it to your code. Example:

```
require 'mechanize'

@client = Mechanize.new()
@client.request_headers = { "Accept-Encoding" => "" }
@client.ignore_bad_chunking = true
@client.follow_meta_refresh = true
#works
#url = 'http://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/7307'

#doesn't work
url = 'http://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/9893'

result = @client.get(url)
pp result
```

The pp at the bottom will print out the page in a nice format for further crawling. It looks like the correct content on my machine.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with it being a redirect issue.  I tried adding that to the code but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: weird, I was able to make it work on my machine. Glad you found a solution though! happy crawling,